# How can I add a hyperlink to an image in an existing PDF file?

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a textbox in pdf which contains an image. Now I want to add hyperlink to that image programatically from code using itext. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [ExtractImages](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=284) and [MyImageRenderListener](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=283) sample code. Rewrite it so that it doesn't extract the images, but use it to get the [ImageRenderInfo](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/ImageRenderInfo.html#getImageCTM%28%29) and use its `getMatrix()` method. The Matrix gives you the coordinates and size of the images in your PDF.

Now use these coordinates to create a link annotation as is done in the [TimetableAnnotations2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=150) example.

Comment: I am able to add hyperlink to a new document created by using itext itself. But right now, I want to open an existing pdf template which contains a textfield named 'L1'(suppose) and place a hyperlink in it. I guess Anchor can be used for hyperlinks when we create a new pdf document and then add anchor to it. Just like I use fields.setFields("T1","Title") to fill textbox named T1 with text "Title", is there any method so that "Title" can be a hyperlink?